# Google sheets API refresh calculations

Tags: google-sheets-api

I've noticed a slight anomolae in Google Sheets v4 API when adding multiple sheets. When adding a sheet that refers to a non-existant sheet (yet created) when you go in and view the sheet once all are added the formula produces an error - *even if* the later sheet is in fact now present.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add a sheet to a workbook that references in a formula 'Named Table'
2. Add a sheet called 'Named Table'

The formula in Sheet 1 will error. Go into the cell and hit return and the calculation refreshes (even though nothing has changed) and it will work fine.

Question: Can this refresh process be programatically triggered for Sheets API v4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be triggered by the API today by doing the same thing the UI is doing -- read the value in the cell & apply an update to that cell with the same value.

Comment: Thanks. Or I guess I could just make sure all the sheets are in the workbook first. Yours is definitely the answer though. Thanks!